# How to provide interactive argument into shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to encrypt password in my shell script and need to pass my predefined variable as a response to the request coming post running one of the shell commands.

I am trying to automate password reset process and need to automatically assign new password as per my shell script logic, for that I need to encrypt my password.

```
#below line will prompt for pwd but i want to sent my variable as response
hashed_pwd=`python -c 'import crypt,getpass; print crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass())'`
echo $hashed_pwd
```

I want to have `hashed_pwd` as a value without asking me to enter the password.

Comment: If you alreay have your password stored in a variable, why do you then invoke `getpass`? Just use your variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have problems with your approach? 
Is it, that you don't know how to pass variables to python, if so, you can do something like

```
hashed_pwd=$(python2 -c "import crypt,getpass; print crypt.crypt($YOURPASS)")
```

Notice the changes I made:
- called python2, since your code is written in python2 to avoid that maybe a python3 interpreter is started instead
- changed the ' to use " which allows variable substitution
- the change from backticks to the `$()` notation is more or less cosmetically

Btw. when I tried to test this, I noticed, that in my environment it seems I have different package versions of crypt. In one crypt needs two arguments (password and salt, where salt has to be a string), in the other, the second argument is optional.

If that is also the case in your system, you could pass it from your shell environment as:

```
python2 -c "import crypt,getpass; print crypt.crypt(getpass.getpass(),'$salt')"
```